# How to make a erc721 that calls destruct after transfer/minted?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, nft

Using the openzeppelin example how can I make so the ERC721 calls 'destruct' upon transfer or minting?

pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/drafts/Counters.sol";

contract GameItem is ERC721Full {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721Full("GameItem", "ITM") public {
    }

    function awardItem(address player, string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256) {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(player, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is ‘destruct’?

Comment: I guess I mean self-destruct

Comment: Whom is gonna self-destrut? The nft token, or the contract making the transfer? What did you try?